# Как можно запроосить у клиента сертификат установленный на его компьютере?

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc, spring-security

Надо чтобы при нажатии на конкретную ссылку браузер запрашивал сертификат которые установленны у клиента на компьютере, вот [сайт](https://www.e-gov.az/az/login/index) где это реализовали. [image: при нажатии на ссылку запрашивается сертификат , который используется для входа в систему]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript тут ни при чём – это ведь обычная SSL авторизация по сертификату, вроде бы? Настраивается на веб сервере. См. настройку [под nginx](http://habrahabr.ru/post/213741/) или [apache](https://www.opennet.ru/base/sec/ssl_cert.txt.html).